# Stuck at serving, or in case of 404 performing two actions in Nginx

Tags: nginx

This is what I need for my static files:

1. If file exists, then serve it
2. If it does not exist, proxy_pass to the cloud provider (Azure in this case)
3. Also, notify an API to download that file from Azure, so that the next request could be served directly from disk.

The first requirement would be solved using the `root /storage`. The second requirement can be achieved using `proxy_intercept_errors on` and `error_page 404 = @reverseProxyBlock`. However, I'm stuck at the third requirement.

I need to somehow notify an API to download that file behind the scenes.

What can I do?